# Call method of another component file angular 2

Tags: function, angular, components

I have two component files: `file1.component.ts` and `file2.component.ts`. On a button event, I want to call a method from file2.component.ts (for example `ngOnInit()`) in file1.component.ts. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>angular2 playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/http.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>
        loading...
    </my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to call `ngOnInit()` method from the `app.component.ts`, in the content-list.component.ts.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question ;) and please share your code.

Comment: Take a look at component interaction in the angular docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: "for example ngOnInit()" is utterly wrong, that's a lifecycle event, not a function to be called btw.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. There is a very good reason you were not allowed to post the link to plnkr. Instead click the `<>` button and share it HERE

Answer (score 3):

Do not use life cycle methods(like ngOnInit..). Write a custom method, if you want use one method in another class you have two options.

1. use `Viewchild()` In first component create object to access any method.

Example:

```
class FirstComponent {

@ViewChild(SecondComponent)
private sec: SecondComponent;

sec.methodName();

}
```

2. Very simple this just extend the first component in second.

Comment: Hi, How can i create a pipe filter in app.component.ts file which filters data by "Name". Example code could be seen in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJhAHne4zA6H0lFog1OI?p=preview). Interesting files would be: app.component.ts, content-list.component.ts and content-filter.pipe.ts. Thanks